# Boto3 AWS S3 bucket creation error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am beginner in Boto3 and working on AWS developer certification. 
I am trying to create a S3 bucket in my account. Below is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto3
from boto3.session import Session
session = Session(aws_access_key_id='asd',aws_secret_access_key='asdas')

s3 = session.resource('s3')
s3.create_bucket(Bucket='myfbucket789076541253334')
```

region_name='ap-south-1'
Then I tried a bunch of others from this link but did not help 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

My code looks like this now

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto3
from boto3.session import Session
session = Session(aws_access_key_id='xyz',aws_secret_access_key='+af',region_name='eu-west-1')

s3 = session.resource('s3')
s3.create_bucket(Bucket='myfbucket789076541253334')
```

I get the below error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S3_bucket.py", line 6, in <module>
    s3.create_bucket(Bucket='myfbucket789076541253334')
  File "/Users/xvz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xvz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "/Users/xvz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/xvz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (IllegalLocationConstraintException) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The unspecified location constrai
nt is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.
```

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Comment: My boto version is 2.48.0

Comment: It does work for `us-east-1`

Answer (score 25):

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/create-bucket.html

> Regions outside of us-east-1 require the appropriate LocationConstraint to be specified in order to create the bucket in the desired region

I believe you need to specify the location constraint when you create bucket. Here's a snippet from http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html

```
response = client.create_bucket(
   ...
    CreateBucketConfiguration={
        'LocationConstraint': 'eu-west-1'
    },
    ...
)
```

Comment: This is correct.  For legacy/backwards-compatibilty reasons, a bucket without a location constraint means the bucket is to be constrained to `us-east-1`.  Sending a creation request for such a bucket to a different regional endpoint fails for that reason.

Comment: Make sure to check your ~/.aws/config to see if you have a different `[default] region=<your region>`